# What is the complexity of strstr in c?

Tags: c, strstr

What is the complexity of strstr in c?
I have looked for the answer to the problem for a long time, but still cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the implementation, but I would be surprised if it were more than O(n).